# Proof of exponential property

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Given $f(x) = \exp(ax)$, then the derivative, by definition is given by $\frac{df}{dx} = a\exp(ax)$. Also, it is known that $f(0) = 1$

I want to prove that $\exp((a+b)x)$  is equal to $\exp(ax)\cdot\exp(bx)$.

So, to do this, I take the derivative of $\exp((a+b)x)$ which results in $(a+b)\exp((a+b)x)$ by definition of the exponential. Next, I take the derivative of $\exp(ax)\cdot\exp(bx)$ which results in $(a+b)\exp(ax)\cdot\exp(bx)$.

Now, I evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}$$[\exp((a+b)x) - \exp(ax)\cdot\exp(bx)]$ at $x = 0$. This results in zero.

My question now is, have I completed the proof. If yes, can someone explain why?

Comment: No. You have two functions $f$ and $g$, that you differentiate, and you check the derivatives are equal at $0$. Does it mean $f$ and $g$ are equal everywhere? Take for instance $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=2x^2$.

Comment: So how would I continue?

Comment: To show that $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$, consider the function $f(x,y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)\exp(-(x+y))$ and show that both first partials are $0$ everywhere, and $f(0,0)=1$, so the $f(x,y) \equiv 1$, and so the equality holds. You can adapt this argument to your situation.

Comment: To show that $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$, consider the function $f(x,y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)\exp(-(x+y))$ and show that both first partials are $0$ everywhere, and $f(0,0)=1$, so the $f(x,y) \equiv 1$, and so the equality holds. You can adapt this argument to your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any function whose derivative is 0 for all $x$ is a constant function.

So what you have shown is that $e^{(a+b)x}-e^{ax}e^{bx}$ is a constant function. Any input, $x$, will yield the same output. So for example $e^{5(a+b)}-e^{5a}e^{5b}=e^{89(a+b)}-e^{89a}e^{88b}= e^{-2(a+b)}-e^{-2a}e^{-2b}$. It doesn’t matter what input we choose, it will give us the same thing.

So how do we find the function value? How do we use this information to show the result?

Comment: Input the value and get the result.

Comment: Those questions were rhetorical. They were meant for the question asker to think about.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I showed exp((a+b)x)−exp(ax)*exp(bx) is 0 when we sub in x = 0. The only reason I subbed in x = 0 is because the definition of the exponential stated at the beginning of the question allows for it. How do I extend this for all value of x? For example, from the definition, I only know that exp((a+b)0) - exp(a*0)*exp(b*0) = 1 - 1 = 0. How can I extend this to exp((a+b)*5) - exp(a*5)*exp(b*5) = 0?

Comment: Let me give you examples of constant functions. f(x)=1, g(x)=2, h(x)=-67. If I input 0 into these functions, I get f(0)=1, g(0)=2, h(0)=-67. If I input

Comment: If I input 4 into these functions, I get f(4)=1, g(4)=2, h(4)=-67. If I input any number y into these functions, I get f(y)=1, g(y)=2, h(y)=-67. @GustoCo